# SQL NOT IN not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases, one which holds the inventory, and another which contains a subset of the records of the primary database.

The following SQL statement is not working:

```
SELECT  stock.IdStock
        ,stock.Descr       
FROM    [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE   stock.IdStock NOT IN
        (SELECT foreignStockId FROM
         [Subset].[dbo].[Products])
```

The not in does not work. Removing the NOT gives the correct results, i.e. products that are in both databases. However, using the NOT IN is not returning ANY results at all.

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have stock.IdStock which are not in foreignStockId at all?

Comment: Do you really have any items in `Inventory` that is not in `Subset`?

Comment: Explain what the query should return. Currently it returns all the stock items where there is no product in the subset referencing it.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

```
SELECT foreignStockId
FROM   [Subset].[dbo].[Products]
```

Probably returns a `NULL`.

A `NOT IN` query will not return any rows if any `NULL`s exists in the list of `NOT IN` values. You can explicitly exclude them using `IS NOT NULL` as below.

```
SELECT stock.IdStock,
       stock.Descr
FROM   [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE  stock.IdStock NOT IN (SELECT foreignStockId
                             FROM   [Subset].[dbo].[Products]
                             WHERE  foreignStockId IS NOT NULL)
```

Or rewrite using `NOT EXISTS` instead.

```
SELECT stock.idstock,
       stock.descr
FROM   [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   [Subset].[dbo].[Products] p
                   WHERE  p.foreignstockid = stock.idstock)
```

As well as having the semantics that you want the execution plan for `NOT EXISTS` is often simpler [as looked at here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/73226).

The reason for the difference in behaviour is down to the  [three valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) used in SQL. Predicates can evaluate to `True`, `False`, or `Unknown`.

A `WHERE` clause must evaluate to `True` in order for the row to be returned but this is not possible with `NOT IN` when `NULL` is present as explained below.

`'A' NOT IN ('X','Y',NULL)` is equivalent to `'A' <> 'X' AND 'A' <> 'Y' AND 'A' <> NULL)`

- 'A' <> 'X'  = `True`
- 'A' <> 'Y'  = `True`
- 'A' <> NULL = `Unknown`

`True AND True AND Unknown` evaluates to `Unknown` per the [truth tables for three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_logic).

The following links have some additional discussion about performance of the various options.

- [Should I use `NOT IN`, `OUTER APPLY`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `EXCEPT`, or `NOT EXISTS`?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)
- [`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)
- [`Left outer join` vs `NOT EXISTS`](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)
- [`NOT EXISTS` vs `NOT IN`](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/)

Comment: This fixed it for me.
Select * From x Where x.y not in( Select Distinct ISNULL(c,0))

Comment: oh my god, indeed select returned null and NOT IN was not working properly. 6 years later I salute you

Answer (score 4):

If **NOT IN** does not work, you may always try to do **LEFT JOIN**. Then filter by **WHERE** using one of the values from the joined table, which are **NULL**. Provided, the value you were joining by *does not contain* any **NULL** value.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my 2 cents:

I've seen SQL Server returning wrong results even when switching to `not exists` and `left join` - **in corrupt databases**. Run DBCC CHECKTABLE on the tables involved, also look at the `NOT IN` query execution plan and rebuild the indexes involved, this should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Case clause to tackle such issues

```
SELECT  stock.IdStock
        ,stock.Descr        
FROM    [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE   (Case when stock.IdStock IN
        (SELECT foreignStockId FROM
        [Subset].[dbo].[Products]) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

this syntax works in SQL Server, Oracle and postgres