# SQL Statements should come out the same, but don't

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

Hey All,

I have the following two queries:

```
select distinct ID from db2.tran tr
where ID not in(
select distinct id from db2.tran
join (select distinct id from db1.client) as c on c.id = tr.id)


select distinct id from db2.tran tr
where id not in (select distinct id from db1.client)
```

Now in my mind, these queries should be equivelant, however, the first one returns rows, and the second one does not.  Am i going crazy or is thier logic behind why these two are not coming out the same.

Thanks

Comment: Does `db1.client` have any `NULL` ids?

Comment: yes, it does, but I'm not sure why that would cause i difference

Comment: `WHERE X NOT IN (1,2,NULL)` etc. always returns zero rows as it is equivalent to `X<>1 AND X<>2 AND X<>NULL` and anything `AND UNKNOWN` is `UNKNOWN` not true.

Comment: `NOT IN` does not handle `NULL` as you would sometimes expect.

Comment: Thanks!  that solved the problem.  I'm suprised i never ran into this issue before (guess i just kept my data cleaner than others programmers  ;)

Comment: Is this just an issue with certain DBs?  I'm currently working in SQL server, but i worked 10 years in Oracle and never ran across this problem.

Comment: @Limey - DBs handle `NULL` differently.  Google `ANSI NULLS` in SQL for config options.

Comment: @Limey - Slight amend to my previous comment. `False` and `Unknown` is `False` of course! You might find this interesting http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Answer (score 2):

With your second query

```
select distinct id
from   db2.tran tr
where  id not in (select distinct id
                  from   db1.client)
```

As the sub query brings back `NULL` values the query as a whole will always return an empty resultset for the reasons described in the comments. (See also [SQL and the Snare of Three Valued Logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/))

With your first query

```
select distinct ID
from   db2.tran tr
where  ID not in(select distinct id
                 from   db2.tran
                        join (select distinct id
                              from   db1.client) as c
                          on c.id = tr.id)
```

One effect of the `JOIN` condition `c.id = tr.id` will be to exclude all `NULL` values from the result of the sub query therefore this issue doesn't arise.

Answer (score 0):

we have seen very inconsistent results when using IN/NOT IN statements.

this should also be equivalent:

```
SELECT
distinct ID 
FROM db2.tran tr
where ID NOT IN (

   SELECT distinct a.id from db2.tran a join db1.client b on (a.id = b.id)

)
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  FWIW the issue is `NULL` and `NOT IN` - `NOT IN` fails when it hits `NULL` since you can't say for certain that a value is `NOT IN NULL` as `NULL` is unknown.