# Different Results from NOT EXISTS and NOT IN

Tags: sql, exists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

I am getting different results in my result set from NOT IN and NOT EXISTS.  Here is the basic query:

The following query will return 300 rows.
`select VendorID from Vendors`

If I add a where clause to only return vendors that are also in the carriers table, I get 50 rows.
`select VendorID from Vendors where VendorID in(select CarrierId from Carriers)`

I would expect that a NOT IN would return the vendors that didn't show up in the query above.  In other words, the 300 vendors minus the 50 that were included above.
`select VendorId from Vendors where VendorId not in(select CarrierId from Carriers)`

This is not the case.  I get 0 rows with the Not In clause.

If I use NOT EXIST, I get the 250 rows I would expect.
`select VendorID from Vendors where NOT EXISTS (select CarrierID from Carriers where CarrierID = VendorID)`

What is the difference here between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS?

Comment: It's definitely `NULL` related. This is a well-known and well-documented issue.

Comment: Ok thanks - there is a NULL value in the subquery.