# Mysql using NOT IN gives empty result. Maybe because of NULL values?

Tags: php, mysql, null, phpmyadmin, notin

Hi I am having the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `workshopmails`
WHERE `workshopmails_mail` NOT
IN (

SELECT workshopklanten_email
FROM `workshopklanten`
)
GROUP BY workshopmails_mail
ORDER BY `workshopmails`.`workshopmails_datum` DESC
```

But although i know this should give a lot of results it gives the message:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (0 rows).
```

I tried it with an older database and got 100+ results now with my newer data it wont work any more the only thing i can think of is because there are some NULL values in it, that where not in the older database

Does anyone know a solution so i can extract the emails?

Thx
Matthy

Comment: `NOT IN (SELECT workshopklanten_email FROM workshopklanten WHERE workshopklanten_email  IS NOT NULL)` would be one way.

Comment: Your awesome! thanks any reason why null values causes this problem?

Comment: [Explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working/5231731#5231731)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin Smith

```
NOT IN (SELECT workshopklanten_email FROM workshopklanten WHERE workshopklanten_email IS NOT NULL)
```

would be one way.

[SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working/5231731#5231731)