# NOT IN not working SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, notin

I have 2 tables , Users and Friends Table, Users have uID, Friends have UID as well, I want to check the UIDs present in Users table but not present in Friends Table,
I am using this query

```
SELECT b.userId 
FROM users b 
where b.userId NOT IN(
  select userId 
  from user_friend
)
```

But it is returning me all the rows of Users Table..
Am I missing something?
Example Data in MYSQL

```
Users Table
1
2
3
4
Friends Table
2
3
4
```

I actually need to get 1

Comment: Give example of the data in your two tables.  Also, are you using mysql or oracle?

Comment: Post the schema of Users and User_friend please

Comment: @IanKenney The schema is pretty straight forward..Both Have UID as PK

Comment: both integer datatype ?

Comment: Are there `NULL` values in the `userid` column in the friends table?

Comment: @IanKenney yes int(16)

Comment: @ypercube no there is not any

Comment: @ypercube would it matter if it where?

Comment: is there any difference between user_friend and Friends table, since in query you have written that and schema you have written Friends

Comment: @GopeshSharma no there is no difference, that was just to make ppl understand

Comment: Is it `UID` or `userid`? Is it `Friends` or `user_friend`? Make up your mind on the names of tables and columns and post a few rows (with all the columns of the tables) and someone will help you.

Comment: Can you please tell us what this returns? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_friend WHERE userid IS NULL;` ?

Comment: @Taemyr Yes it would matter. If there is (even one NULL) in the friends table, no row will be returned by the query (and the way to solve the problem is to rewrite the query with NOT EXISTS, as Tippa's answer.) The strange thing is that the OP says that the query returns **all rows** and not 0 rows. It's confusing - and the only possible explanation is that the OP has not provided accurate information.

Comment: @Taemyr  See: **[SQL NOT IN not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT b.userId 
FROM users b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM user_friend
   WHERE b.userId = user_friend.userId
);
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user_friend ) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Comment: @TippaRaj It would have been better, if an explanation was given on why the `NOT IN` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT b.userId 
FROM users b 
where b.userId NOT IN(
  select user_friend.userId 
  from user_friend
)
```

Comment: same result.. there is nothing different

Answer (score 0):

A Work Around for your query

```
SELECT  U.UserId
FROM    Users U
EXCEPT
SELECT  F.UserId
FROM    Friends F
```

Comment: I think U2 should be user_friend?  Otherwise this should always return no rows.