# mySql where not in, rows with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Im having a problem where when i execute a sql statement, it fetches no rows when any row has a null value in a certain column.

My sql statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM cb_users u
LEFT JOIN Story1 s ON s.ID = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN cb_users_pitches p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM cb_contact_tickets WHERE ticket_status IN ('open', 'unresponsive', 'declined')) AND role = 'filmmaker' AND u.status = 'idle' 
ORDER BY u.last_login
```

I think it has something to do where im checking user_ids against user ids that could possibly be null. Any possible work around?

Absolutly nothing when a null value is included when a row has a null value in user_id from the cb_contact_tickets table

Sample data for when there isnt a null value:

```
user_id, role, status, last_login, login_count, signed, joined, longform, signed_ip, signed_dt, user_score, fav_director, fav_film, fav_act, board_member, votes, about_me, has_image, invite_date, vimeo_id, access_token, access_token_secret, vimeo_group, pm_notify, join_process, join_step, future_role, primary_group, unidle_date, conversion, previous_role, points, ID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Password, nCity, primary_country, primary_city, temporary_password, Status2, Status, Last_Contact, Next, Comments, Rank, Notes, Directed, Nar_List, Nar_Links, Other_List, Other_Links, Interest, Criticism, Internet, City, Available, Heard, Updated, Joined, Contact, Agreement, TimeZone, ChatTime, signname, signdate, lastlogin, numlogins, lastIP, Pitch1, nobudget, GroupNo, LinkPop, P2Late, Pnote, New, DueDate, Note, ShowDD, PastDue, Reading, PDDate, DaysLate, Cities, c3login, c3logins, dwdate, tnote, date_applied, pitch_id, pitch, user_id, dt, deleted, page, light
'515', 'filmmaker', 'idle', '2013-04-27 04:06:18', '5', '2013-04-16 01:55:00', 'accept', 'accept', '122.176.139.62', '2013-04-16 02:19:44', '0', '', '', '', '1', '0', '', 'no', '2013-01-19 12:59:51', '', '', '', 'no', 'on', '1', '5', 'filmmaker', '9', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '515', 'anurag.sikder@gmail.com', 'Anurag', 'Sikder', '69b0f8b481b30559d4ca1701e33762104f4f66a1', 'India', '', '', 'no', 'billion', 'NEW', '0000-00-00', 'so should he be in new?  or are we waiting for more?  put him in new if he should be.\r\n\r\n12.22 i think i mis-communicated a little. he wasn\'t finished with what i said below that he was going to send..so probably he should have been in new-i e\'d him again-cjs\r\n\r\nif he\'s about to send more then wait for it til we make him new so he gets reviewed once.. - mcs\r\n10.5 I found his links in the old feedback form but he still says he will be sending his newer work-cjs\r\n9.20 e\'d for film -cjs\r\nASK HIM TO SEND HIS FILM  -- last time said he was finishing it.\r\nRESPONDED TO REVISIT EMAIL\r\n\r\nwas finishing his film.  revisit later or if he uploads it. \r\n1.24 didn\'t get email, resent again\r\n1.18: first email.  he said would upload. ', '', '0', '', 'Yes', 'I have till now directed only on film called Self-Service. The film was completed in December. Till now, it has not been screened anywhere yet.', 'Director Links:  1. Self Service- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axkfK5qg8Z0\r\n2. All Shook Up- http://youtu.be/rY98e-ZYYks\r\n', '', '', 'The opportunity to learn more about cultural and methodological differences between directors from different parts of the globe. The chance to have fun and create something in collaboration with so many creative minds.', 'Yes if it is founded on honest and clear reason. ', 'Yes', 'India', 'January End', 'Facebook', '2013-01-19 12:59:57', '0000-00-00', '', 'False', NULL, NULL, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '', '', 'Yes', '0', '0', 'FALSE', NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '0', '0000-00-00', '0', 'In India, New Delhi, Haryana, West Bengal, Andhra Pradesh and Maharashtra.', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '0000-00-00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'522', 'filmmaker', 'idle', '2013-04-09 10:17:18', '2', '2012-09-17 19:08:29', 'accept', 'accept', '186.80.98.141', '2012-09-17 19:14:17', '0', 'Emir Kusturica', 'The mirror (Tarkovsky)', 'Daniel Day - Lewis', '1', '0', 'www.vimeo.com/18461027                      (As actor - Ganster and director of actors)\r\n\r\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vl07w4CBEN8                   (As director)\r\n\r\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', 'no', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', '', 'no', 'on', '1', '5', 'filmmaker', '9', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1575', '522', 'andres9filmscolombia@hotmail.com', 'AndrÃ©s', 'Sandoval', '6482e88cf393c0667faa74bb2a109ab9531102b0', 'Bogota, Colombia', '', '', 'no', 'Active', 'NEW', '0000-00-00', 'new email:  andres9filmscolombia@hotmail.com\r\nold email:  andresando_23@hotmail.com\r\n\r\nprompted 1.27\r\ninviting 1.23', 'I: This is Yango\\\'s \\\"Actor\\\'s Director\\\" he has two teasers for this whacked out horror movie and co-directed a fairly slick looking music video.', '0', '', 'Yes', 'MARINA\\\'S HUSBAND (Director, Writer and Producer)\r\nRESURRECCJA (Resurrection) (Writer, Producer and CoDirector with Yango Gonzalez)\r\nOMEGA EFFECT (Teaser for TV) (Writer, Director and producer)\r\nFILE 0 (Pilot of Omega Effect -TV series) (Writer, Director and producer)\r\nPOKER (Feature)( Actor\\\'s director) \r\nEL DORADO INSANE ASYLUM (Actor\\\'s Director- Actor)\r\nTHE IMPORTANCE OF A MINUTE (Assistant director)\r\nMEMORIES (Cameraman)\r\n', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TARV8OWTFKA\r\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vl07w4CBEN8\r\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDT2IJXZgdo&feature=related', 'SOBREVIVIENTES- SURVIVORS (VideoClip Group Las Plagas) (Writer, CoDirector With Mateo Stivelberg)\r\n\r\n', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXjXKOmvtiQ', 'I\\\'d like to tell a good story in a short time', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Bogota, Colombia', 'Now', 'Yango Gonzalez', '2012-02-04 16:33:40', '0000-00-00', '', 'False', NULL, NULL, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '190.255.243.89', '', 'Yes', '0', '0', 'FALSE', NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '0', '0000-00-00', '0', 'Around Bogota', '2013-08-22 21:17:00', '411', '0000-00-00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'657', 'filmmaker', 'idle', '2013-06-19 15:16:33', '38', '2012-09-12 09:43:58', 'accept', 'accept', '89.136.169.251', '2012-09-13 04:24:20', '0', 'Welles, Tarr, Hitchcock', 'Pociag, Suna no onna', 'Peter O\\\'Toole', '1', '0', '', 'no', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', '', 'no', 'on', '1', '5', 'filmmaker', '9', NULL, NULL, NULL, '3207', '657', 'atgraph@gmail.com', 'Adrian', 'Tudor', '057f4b9ac7f3a4465a8013cce98775b6784c3168', 'Romania', '', '', 'no', 'Active', 'NEW', '0000-00-00', '8.15 he\\\'s been logging in, emailed him\r\n5.29 he\\\'s been under-studying Act 3\\\'s/Refrains.. told him it would be a while, slight prompt for him to pick a main story gap.\r\n3.6 pre-welcomed, told prob bring in in April. ', 'great stuff, not as narrative as exprimental and noir-ish black and white and concepty, image-based.  A little wim wenders on the trailer to curtain. ', '0', '', 'Yes', '2007 - Anoxia - Director, Writer, Sound, Editor\r\n2008 - On the Same Road - Director, Writer, Music, Editor\r\n2008 - Quasi Nihil II - Director, Writer, Music, Editor\r\n2009 - House of Veils - Director, Writer, Music, Editor\r\n2010 - Curtain - Director, Writer, Music, Editor', 'www.adriantudor.com/film.html', 'As director:\r\n...sur tonalite - 2007 - Documentary with Gheorghe Zamfir\r\n#11 - 2008 - Music Video\r\n', '', 'The diversity of ideas that can be found when filmmakers from all over the world are gathered together.', 'Yesy', 'Yes', 'Romania', 'March', 'Search Engine', '2011-08-15 11:33:06', '0000-00-00', '', 'False', NULL, NULL, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '89.136.169.251', '', 'Yes', '0', '0', 'FALSE', NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '0', '0000-00-00', '0', 'Any other city in Romania', '2013-08-28 04:15:17', '541', '0000-00-00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'732', 'filmmaker', 'idle', '2013-04-23 21:01:18', '24', '2012-09-19 01:27:30', 'accept', 'accept', '218.186.19.10', '2012-09-19 04:00:25', '0', 'Akira Kurosawa ', 'Rashomon ', 'Leung Chew Wai', '1', '0', 'I am a home tutor, writer of science assessment books and filmmaker. So far, I have made 5 short films of various genres from silent comedies to period wuxia (Chinese martial arts). ', 'no', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', '', 'no', 'on', '1', '5', 'filmmaker', '9', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1560', '732', 'tingszukiong@gmail.com', 'Szu Kiong ', 'Ting', '8a79f4d72cc10b414e55db554f112de27701051c', 'Singapore', '', '', 'no', 'billion', 'NEW', '0000-00-00', '8/20: dropped out, thought he would have shot by now and had work.. willing to come back later. \r\nEmailed - 3/15 - told him we would contact him the next time we need someone.\r\nVery professional Asian TV stuff with a good amount of creativity.  ', '', '0', '', 'Yes', 'MY KEYS (8min) \r\n(Writer/Director)\r\n- Nominated for Best Short Film in 4th Asian Festival of First Films \r\n\r\nMICHELLE (8min)\r\n(Director)\r\n- Selected for Asian Film Symposium \r\n\r\nTHE TRIUMPH (8min)\r\n(Writer/Director)\r\n- Won Best Sound award in Singapore Management University Film Festival \r\n\r\nTHE FOREST SPIRITS (10 min) \r\n(Writer/Director)\r\n- Curator\\\'s Pick in Maskara Shorties \r\n- Curator\\\'s Pick in Sinema Showoff The Oriental Show \r\n- Nominated for Best Sound in 2nd Singapore Short Film Awards', '- http://www.cultureunplugged.com/documentary/watch-online/filmedia/play/607/My-Keys\r\n- http://vimeo.com/14940649 (password: wuxia)', '', '', 'I have always wanted to be acquainted with other filmmakers around the world and look out for opportunities to work or collaborate with them. I believe that independent filmmakers who are aspiring to do feature-length films but are lack of funds should work together in some way or another. Recently I have brought together three filmmakers including me to brainstorm on a feature-length film directed by three different directors. One of them is the German lady director, Juliane Block. When she told me of collabfeature during the discussion, I am immediately thrilled. ', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Singapore', 'Immediately', 'From an existing member, Juliane Block', '2012-09-18 13:22:26', '0000-00-00', '', 'False', NULL, NULL, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '218.186.19.10', '', 'Yes', '0', '0', 'FALSE', NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '0', '0000-00-00', '0', 'Malaysia, Bangkok, Hong Kong, China ', '2011-08-13 03:12:26', '27', '0000-00-00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Sample Data from the contact_tickets table

```
# ticket_id, captain_id, user_id, date_opened, date_closed, ticket_status, comments, group_id, pm_sent, task, declined
'94', '1733', '1718', '2013-08-24 12:44:05', NULL, 'open', 'Contacted on 24/08/2013', '3', '0', '', ''
```

Comment: Post sample data from your tables.

Comment: Really verbose, your example data :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL NOT IN not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three methods which is best to select values present in one table but missing in another one. They are as follows:

1. LEFT JOIN(Using IS NULL)
2. NOT IN
3. NOT EXISTS

Looking at your scenario it would be best to avoid `NOT IN` which  is trivalent, i. e. it can return TRUE, FALSE or NULL. `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN(Using IS NULL)` would be an ideal match in your case.

For more info: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: The query does not return Nulls. It returns no rows at all.

Comment: +1 for providing a specific solution..:)Sorry i misunderstood the  question..my bad..well I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's a problem with `NOT IN` and SQL's ternary logic. See a much more detailed explanation at: **[SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)**

Solution is to change the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`. The `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN 
      ( SELECT user_id 
        FROM cb_contact_tickets 
        WHERE ticket_status IN ('open', 'unresponsive', 'declined')
      ) 
  AND role = 'filmmaker' 
  AND u.status = 'idle'
```

becomes:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM cb_contact_tickets AS t 
        WHERE t.ticket_status IN ('open', 'unresponsive', 'declined')
          AND t.user_id = u.user_id 
      ) 
  AND role = 'filmmaker' 
  AND u.status = 'idle'
```

Comment: According to [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) MySQL performs better using the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` method. The article is 4 years old though, so MySQL could have made some improvements that I am not aware of (certainly the notion mentioned that SQL-Server doesn't optimise the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` method to an anti semi join is antiquated for recent versions).

Comment: @GarethD For SQL-Server, read this recent article: **[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)** For MySQL, I'd say testing is needed.

Comment: I stand corrected. I could have sworn I have seen SQL-Server use an anti-semi join on a LEFT JOIN. But I can't recreate it now in any version. I am quite happy to be proved wrong in this case because I much prefer `NOT EXISTS` anyway (subjective but I think it is more logical to read).