# Using NOT IN function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT products.name from products WHERE products.id 
NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(products.id) FROM timer_completed
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = com_jobcard.product_id)
```

In the above query `SELECT DISTINCT(products.id) FROM timer_completed`  will return multiple values but I need the products which are not in that result set, so I have used `NOT IN` function but it returns error. Could you suggest me a better way to achieve this.

Comment: what error does it return?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `sub-query` returns some `NULL` values which will make the `NOT IN` to [**`fail`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)(will not throw error). Use `NOT EXISTS` to do this

```
SELECT products.NAME 
FROM   products p 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   timer_completed 
                          INNER JOIN com_jobcard 
                                  ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id 
                   WHERE  p.id = com_jobcard.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. I hope this will work..

`NOT IN` operation would fail if the result set being probed returns a `NULL`. In such a case, the results of a `NOT IN` query is `0` rows while a `NOT EXISTS` query would still show the rows present in the one table but not in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

> The best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a `LEFT
>   JOIN` / `IS NULL` or `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`.

You can make use of `LEFT JOIN` here.

```
SELECT P.name
FROM 
    products P
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT(products.id) FROM timer_completed
      INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
      INNER JOIN products ON products.id = com_jobcard.product_id) T
     ON P.product_id <> T.product_id
WHERE T.product_id IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.