# Sql Query to fetch Resultset

Tags: sql

The data contains over `360K` numbers so make sure the query is optimised.

DATABASE

TABLE consist of data

```
+---------+
| Styles  |
+---------+
|  1 
|  2
|  3
|  4
|  7
|  8
|  9
|  10 
+---------+
```

Numbers i HAVE

```
+--------+
|Numbers |
+--------+
| 4
| 5  
| 6 
| 9 
+--------+
```

Numbers NOT IN Styles are suppose `5,6` how do I get them.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Try selecting distinct bus_id and see how many values you get back. There looks like some duplicates.

Comment: Do you want to know the 3 missing numbers?

Comment: `numbers` is more readable than `nos` by the way!!!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: TODA - Using Oracle 11g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL NOT IN not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Use left or right join this sample is using left joint

```
select b.col1, 'is missing'
from    (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) as b(col1)
        left join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(9),(10)) as a(col1) on b.col1 = a.col1
where   a.col1 is null
```

Comment: What is your sql server name? MS SQL, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Create the ten numbers you are interested in on-the-fly and remove those present in the table. E.g.:

```
select row_number() over (order by bus_id) from table fetch first 10 rows only
except
select bus_id from table;
```

The syntax depends on the DBMS of course. You may be using a DBMS where you'd work with rownum, limit, top, minus, a values clause or whatever instead.