# Regarding the working mechanism of NOT IN clause in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Following are the results of my sql queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(department_id) 
from employees 
ORDER BY department_id;
```

Result:

### DEPARTMENT_ID

```
       10
       20
       30
       40
       50
       60
       70
       80
       90
      100
      110
```

Then:

```
SELECT department_id 
FROM departments 
ORDER BY department_id;
```

### DEPARTMENT_ID

```
       10
       20
       30
       40
       50
       60
       70
       80
       90
      100
      110
      120
      130
      140
      150
      160
      170
      180
      190
      200
      210
      220
      230
      240
      250
      260
      270
```

When I execute the Following Query, I get the result:

```
SELECT department_id 
from departments  
where department_id IN (select distinct(department_id) from employees)  
ORDER BY department_id;
```

### DEPARTMENT_ID

```
       10
       20
       30
       40
       50
       60
       70
       80
       90
      100
      110
```

However, the following query returns "NO Rows Selected" when I execute the following query:

```
SELECT department_id 
from departments  
WHERE department_id NOT IN (select distinct(department_id) from employees)   
ORDER BY department_id;
```

What I was expected was the Id of departments that are not present in Employees table. 
I feel its a beginner's mistake however i am not able to resolve this issue. Any help would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Please show the sample input data (table row values)

Comment: does employee table have any null departmentid that you haven't shown us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

Comment: @Martin Smith Yepp that was indeed the case! I figured that out after reading the answer from Gordon Linoff down below. However, I am still not clear why the null value of department_id of one employees caused the query to produce no result.. Can you help me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried explaining this here. Not sure how successfully... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48643/query-to-find-guids-not-in-null-containing-subquery-returns-no-results/48657#48657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because at least one `department_id` in `employees is`NULL`.  When any value in the`NOT IN`list is`NULL`, no rows are returned at all.

To fix this, I simply recommend *always* using `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery:

```
SELECT d.department_id 
FROM departments d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees e WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id)   
ORDER BY d.department_id;
```

(Or by using a `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE`.)

You *could* fix this using a `WHERE` clause in the subquery.  I think it is better to use a construct that does what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! However, the results need to be ordered by d.department_id i guess!! :)