# Why is empty subquery in SQL IN sometimes treated as null

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-in

I noticed the following strange behavior in SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE col NOT IN ((SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 2))
```

returns **all** records (i.e. the subquery result is the empty set) while

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE col NOT IN (1, (SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 2))
```

return **no** records (i.e. the subquery result is null)

Got the same result in DBFiddle with postgresql and mysql. Sqlite returns no records with both queries because of the extra parenthesis.

Am I thinking completely wrong here?

Could not find anything in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The background is I have a method to convert `@Param` to `@Param1, @Param2, @Param3...` where the number of parameters come from a sequence.

I want the method to also work for the empty sequence and in that case I replace with `(SELECT null WHERE 1 = 2)` but it doesn't work when the input is `NOT IN (1, @Param)`

Is there some other solution to this?

Here is the fiddle code

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl (col int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES (2);
```

I expected the second query to return "2"

Comment: What did you actually try? Post the Fiddle code so others can test this.

Comment: You can do `NOT IN (SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 2 UNION ALL SELECT 1)` so it is treated as `NOT IN` sub query rather than `NOT IN (scalar)`

Comment: The two queries aren't the same. The first checks whether something is contained in the empty set. Since that set is empty, `NOT IN empty` is always true. In the second case though, you have a somewhat invalid query. You can't have an `IN` clause that contains different types of items, much less scalar values *and* result sets. The query compiles only because the subquery returns an empty set BUT that has to be cast to the same type as the first value. And, due to SQL's quirks that translate UNKNOWN to NULL, empty is also converted to NULL

Comment: In short, it's a SQL quirk and a know problem of the language (not the relational model), that unknown or empty data is converted to NULL

Comment: `The background is I have a method to convert @Param to @Param1, @Param2, @Param3... where the number of parameters come from a sequence.` this sounds like the real issue, what are you actually doing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks i see now. In the documentation the "[,...n]" only applies to the expression, not the subquery! Some optimization converts the expression in the first query to a subquery. Seems like sqlite is the correct one here returning nothing in both queries. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: No, SQLite is wrong. `IN empty` has a *very* well known value, false, which means `NOT IN` will be true

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes but doesn't the extra paranthesis makes it an expression instead of a subquery

Comment: @siggemannen, what is wrong with a parameterized IN clause?

Comment: @adrianm no it doesn't. Parentheses group expressions, they don't modify their results.  If you wrote `NOT IN (SELECT ID from someothertable)` the parentheses wouldn't convert the subquery results to a single value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IN` syntax is

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN   
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]  
    )
```

In your first example you are using the `subquery` route.

In the second example you are providing a list of `expression`. These are scalar values. A sub query is only accepted in this context if it can be coerced to a scalar value (returns `0` or `1` rows)

It is usual that an empty result set will return `NULL` when used as a scalar value.

You also see this with

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 2)
```

[`test_expression NOT IN(NULL)` returns no rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working).

This is the exact opposite behaviour to `test_expression NOT IN (empty_set)` (returns every row including ones where `test_expression` is `NULL`)

You can combine the values with `UNION ALL` to keep it as a sub query and prevent an empty set being coerced to `NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Tbl
WHERE  col NOT IN (SELECT 1 WHERE  1 = 2
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 1)
```