Query with "not in" (oracle) doesn't work
I have these two queries that should normally return the same result but this is the case. The second returns 0 while the first returns a considerable number.
SELECT count(dv.ID) FROM table1 dv WHERE (
table1.colonne in ('CLOS')
AND table1.date <= TO_DATE('03/09/2023 00:59:13','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 poste WHERE 
poste.ID_tab = dv.ID ));


SELECT count(dv.ID) FROM table1 dv WHERE (
table1.colonne in ('CLOS')
AND table1.date <= TO_DATE('03/09/2023 00:59:13','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND dv.ID not IN ( SELECT poste.ID_tab FROM table2 poste  ) 
);

Any explanation for this please

Probably SELECT poste.ID_tab FROM table2 returns at least one NULL. In which case dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5231712/73226 and likely many other such Qs
